# FCM reports Received/impressions/open Counts are showing zero value

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, report

On the FCM reports, Received/impressions/open Counts are showing zero value.
Only "sends" is correct.
I tried to open the app with a tap to Notification, But can't see the received and open count.
How can I track the received and open count on here?
What I have to do anything on the app?
[image]

Comment: Did you get an explanation for this? We are seeing the same thing

Comment: I solved that issue, You need to install the firebase analysis

Comment: @UPManager how do I implement the analysis ? In the service worker? I can't find any documentation after Googling for hours. Just the same link over and over: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=web

Comment: I implements the analysis for my mobile app.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android#java
Here you can see to installation, there have all platforms.
Just need install and configuration for that

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. Solution was: add analytics **label**. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#adding-analytics-labels-to-messages for more details.